# How to solve and find the value of $\log k$ equation

Tags: logarithms, mathematical-physics

I am doing a mathematics problem where the problem equation led me to below conclusion:

$$\log k = 52.79$$

Now I am not sure how to solve and get value of $k$? What way we can find the value of $k$?

Comment: What does $\log $ *mean*?  Answer that and that answers your question.  Seriously.

Comment: $a=b\implies 10^a=10^b $.

Comment: I am a college student and my knowledge of logs is that it gives the exponential terms that a number should be multiplied how many times - I am not sure still how to solve the question. The issue I am facing is how to solve 10 exponent 52.79

Comment: So $\log $ of $k$ is how many times you must multiply ten by so get $k$.  So wouldn't that mean $k$ is what you get if you multiply $10$ by itself $52.79$?

Comment: What is $10^{\log k}$?

Comment: "The issue I am facing is how to solve 10 exponent 52.79"  Oh.  $10^{52.79}$ is $10^{52.79}$.  That *IS* the answer.  You don't have to say anything more.  $10^{52.79}$ is a perfectly legitimate well expressed number.

Comment: I am not sure then - is k = 5.279 then? Am I correct in my understanding

Comment: No.  $k = 10^{52.79}$.

Comment: It should be the *DEFINITION* that $\log A = B \iff 10^B = k$.  So $\log k = 52.79 \iff 10^{52.79} = k$.  So *THAT* is the answer you are done.  If we need to express that in scentific notation that is $10^{52.79} = 10^{52 + .79} = 10^{.79} \time 10^{52}$.  Plug $10^{.79}$ into a calculator......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\log k = 52.79$

$10^{\log k}=k = 10^{52.79}$

That's it you are done.  But if you are asked to express $10^{52.79}$ as workable value in scientific notation then:

$10^{52.79} = 10^{52}\times 10^{.79} \approx 6.16595\times 10^{52}$.

So that is *APPROXIMATELY* $61,659,500,186,148,216,632,034,834,387,861,000,000,000,000,000,000,000$.  I can't do the last several values because ..... no-one cares.

That's good enough for government work.

Comment: Yes I understand the point but how did you calculate 10 to power .79  without calculator - is there a generic way to find it mentally or calculating?

Comment: In the days before calculators, people published tables of logarithms (and "antilogarithms"), and you would look for $.79$ in one of those tables, and get the answer that way. Or you would take out your slide rule and use the log scale on it. Calculators have made log tables and slide rules obsolete.

Comment: " is there a generic way to find it easily without calculator?" Only if you have a slide rule in your closet.  I didn't caluculate $10^{.79}$.  I plugged it into a calculator.

Comment: You could spend several *HOURS* attempting to figure out the $\sqrt[100]{10^{79}}$  by approximation.  BUt I don't recommend it.